# How to use patch for a variable in PyTest

Tags: python, pytest, patch, pytest-mock

I have below Python code:

```
#datamanager.py    

import os

BASE_DIR = '' #SOME_VALUE
data_list = '' #SOME_VALUE
loaded_data = dict.fromkeys(data_list)

def update_data():
    for key, current_model in loaded_data.items():
        mod_dir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, key)
        if not os.path.exists(mod_dir):
            print("Model dir not present")
            continue
        model_files = os.listdir(mod_dir)
        if not model_files:
            print("Model dir is empty")
            continue
```

I am writing a pytest to test if `mod_dir` exist or not. I have to mock this as initially `mod_dir` will not be present. To do this, there is for loop which loop over `loaded_data`. I am trying to patch this variable but looks like this is not possible. I am trying to do something like below:

```
def test_update_models():
    mock_loaded_data = {'some_data': 'data_file'}
    with patch('datamanager.loaded_data', new=mock_loaded_data):
        update_data()
```

But I keep getting attribute error that `loaded_data` not found. I think it's not possible to patch the values of variables. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find that `patch.object` works here.

However, if you are okay with editing the code under test, I'd recommend enabling the loaded data to be passed into the function (i.e. dependency injection):

```py
def update_data(data=None):
    if data is None:
        data = loaded_data
    for key, current_model in data.items():
        ...
```

Then you can call `update_data(mock_loaded_data)` in your test, and the function has become a bit more flexible/reusable.